Bayesian Transformer for (Deep) Reinforcement Learning Using Variational Inference
I am very new to Bayesian Deep Learning and I am developing a Bayesian Transformer for navigating bsuite's Deep Sea (deterministic) environment to learn the transition mechanism. As of now I am only passing the current_state and expect the model to predict the next_state and reward. The non bayesian version of this model performs decently. This is my network:
"""
Transformer architecture for transition network
"""


class BayesianLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features: int, out_features: int, posterior=Normal, prior=1.0, bias=False, name=''):
        super(BayesianLinear, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight_mu = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
        self.weight_ro = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
        self.bias = bias
        if self.bias:
            self.bias_mu = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features))
            self.bias_ro = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features))

        self.prior = Normal(0, prior)
        self.posterior = posterior
        self.reset_parameters()

    def kl(self):
        weight_posterior = self.posterior(self.weight_mu, F.softplus(self.weight_ro))

        kl_div = kl_divergence(weight_posterior, self.prior).sum()
        if self.bias:
            bias_posterior = self.posterior(self.bias_mu, self.bias_ro)
            kl_div += kl_divergence(bias_posterior, self.prior).sum()

        return kl_div

    def reset_parameters(self):
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.weight_mu)
        # start with a very small variance (like a point estimate)
        nn.init.constant_(self.weight_ro, 1e-3)
        if self.bias:
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.bias_mu)
            nn.init.constant_(self.bias_ro, 1e-2)

    def sample_posterior(self):
        weight = self.posterior(self.weight_mu, F.softplus(self.weight_ro)).rsample()

        if self.bias:
            bias = self.posterior(self.bias_mu, F.softplus(self.bias_ro)).rsample()
        else:
            bias = None

        return weight, bias

    def forward(self, input):
        weight, bias = self.sample_posterior()

        return F.linear(input, weight, bias)


class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, heads=1, prior=1.0):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.heads = heads
        self.head_dim = embed_size//heads

        # creating vectors for query, key, value
        self.queries = BayesianLinear(self.head_dim, self.head_dim, bias=False, prior=prior, name='queries')
        self.keys = BayesianLinear(self.head_dim, self.head_dim, bias=False, prior=prior, name='keys')
        self.values = BayesianLinear(self.head_dim, self.head_dim, bias=False, prior=prior, name='values')
        # combining all the calculated multi-headed attention to get the entire embedding
        self.fully_connected_out = BayesianLinear(heads*self.head_dim, embed_size, prior=prior, name='MHA out')

    def forward(self, queries, keys, values):
        """

        :param queries:
        :param keys:
        :param values:

        Attention(Q,K,V) = softmax(Q*K.T/sqrt(embed_size)) * V

        :return: attention
        """
        N = queries.shape[0] # batch size
        # print('Queries:',queries.shape)
        value_len, key_len, query_len = values.shape[1], keys.shape[1], queries.shape[1] # depends on the sequence length

        # split embedding into #heads
        queries = queries.reshape(N, query_len, self.heads, self.head_dim)
        keys = keys.reshape(N, key_len, self.heads, self.head_dim)
        values = values.reshape(N, value_len, self.heads, self.head_dim)

        values = self.values(values)
        keys = self.keys(keys)
        queries = self.queries(queries)

        # dot product of queries & keys
        # for each token in the target, how much to pay attention to each token in the input of source sequence
        # output shape: (N, #heads, query_len, key_len)
        queries_X_keys = torch.einsum("nqhd,nkhd->nhqk",[queries, keys])

        # multiply the softmax of scaled [queries]X[keys] by values
        queries_X_keys_scaled = torch.softmax(queries_X_keys/self.embed_size**0.5, dim=3) # normalising across the key dim

        # output shape: (N, query_len, #heads, head_dim) #Note: key_len == value_len
        attention = torch.einsum("nhql,nlhd->nqhd",[queries_X_keys_scaled,values])
        # reshape it to embedding dimension
        attention = attention.reshape(N, query_len, self.heads*self.head_dim)

        out = self.fully_connected_out(attention)

        return out, attention

class TransformerBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, heads, dropout, forward_expansion, prior=1.0):
        super().__init__()

        self.attention = MultiHeadAttention(embed_size, heads, prior)

        self.norm = nn.LayerNorm(embed_size)

        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
            BayesianLinear(embed_size, forward_expansion*embed_size, prior=prior, name='transformer_mlp_0'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            BayesianLinear(forward_expansion*embed_size, embed_size, prior=prior, name='transformer_mlp_1')
        )

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, query, key, value): #mask
        """
        concatenate input embedding with output of attention & normalise
        passing norm1 output to feed forward network
        concatenate norm1 output with feedforward layer and pass through another normalisation layer

        :param value:
        :param key:
        :param query:
        :param mask:
        :return:
        """
        attention, self.attention_scores = self.attention(query, key, value)

        x = self.dropout(
            self.norm(attention + query)
        )

        forward = self.mlp(x)

        out = self.dropout(
            self.norm(forward + x)
        )

        return out

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    """
    Input sequence is embedded in model embedding dimension
    Contains multi-head self attention blocks to encode embedding
    ENCODER BLOCK(s) contain:
        1. ATTENTION BLOCK (multi head)
        2. SKIP CONNECTION & NORMALISE
        3. FEED FWD MLP N/W
        4. SKIP CONNECTION & NORMALISE
    """
    def __init__(self, config, n_state: int, n_action: int,  dropout:float, max_timesteps:int, device):
        super().__init__()
        self.device = device

        self.embed_size = config["hidden_dim"]

        self.norm = nn.LayerNorm(config["hidden_dim"])
        self.embed_state = BayesianLinear(n_state, config["hidden_dim"], prior=config['network_prior'],  name='embed_state').to(device)
        self.embed_action = nn.Embedding(n_action, config["hidden_dim"]).to(device)
        self.embed_timestep = nn.Embedding(max_timesteps, config["hidden_dim"]).to(device)

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                TransformerBlock(config["hidden_dim"], config['heads'], dropout, config['forward_expansion'], config['network_prior']) for _ in range(config['num_encoder_layers'])
            ]
        )

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

        self.to(device)

    def forward(self, timesteps: torch.tensor, states: torch.tensor, actions: torch.tensor):#mask
        """
        Performs the forward pass on the current state, action input, & masks for key, value and query
        """
        N, seq_len, state_dim = states.shape

        embedded_timestep = self.embed_timestep(timesteps)

        # concat of input state embeddings & positional time embeddings
        embedded_state = self.dropout(
            self.norm(self.embed_state(states)*self.embed_size**0.5 # scaling according to the original transformer paper
            + embedded_timestep)
        )
        
        # concat of input action embeddings & positional time embeddings
        embedded_action = self.dropout(
            self.norm(self.embed_action(actions) * (self.embed_size ** 0.5)  # scaling according to the original transformer paper
            + embedded_timestep)
        )
        # print('Embedded action with timestep:',embedded_action.shape,'\n',embedded_action)

        # stack states and actions in a sequence and reshape as
        # (
        # s_0, a_0, ## sequence0 of batch
        # s_1, a_1, ## sequence1 of batch
        # s_2, a_2 ## sequence2 of batch
        # ...
        # )
        out = torch.stack(
            (
                embedded_state,
                embedded_action
            ), dim=2
        ).view(N, -1, self.embed_size)

        for i, transformer_layer in enumerate(self.layers):
            out = transformer_layer(out, out, out) # value, query, key

        return out

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config: dict, states: int, actions: list,
                 dropout=0.1, max_steps=1000,
                 device=torch.device):
        super().__init__()

        self.context_length = config["context_length"] # 1
        self.latent_dim = self.context_length + config["hidden_dim"] # 8
        self.num_actions = len(actions)
        self.max_T = max_steps
        self.states = states
        self.loss_function = torch.nn.MSE
        self.to(device)
        self.loss = 0

        self.encoder = Encoder(config, states, self.num_actions, dropout, max_steps, device)

        self.optimizer = torch.nn.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=config["learning_rate"]) # learning_rate=1e-1

        ### predictions
        self.predict_rtg = nn.Sequential(
            BayesianLinear(config["hidden_dim"], 1, prior=config['network_prior'], name='pred_rtg_1')
        ).to(device)
        self.predict_state = nn.Sequential(
            BayesianLinear(config["hidden_dim"], states, prior=config['network_prior'], name='pred_state_1')
        ).to(device)

    def encode(self, timesteps, state, action): #mask
        out = self.encoder(timesteps, state, action) #mask

        return out

    def kl_divergence(self):
        total_kl = 0
        for module in self.modules():
            if isinstance(module, BayesianLinear):
                # print('Module:',module.name,'\tKL:',module.kl())
                total_kl += module.kl()

        return total_kl

    def forward(self, step: torch.Tensor, observations: torch.Tensor, actions: torch.Tensor):

        encoded_output = self.encode(step, observations, actions)
        
        return_preds = self.predict_rtg(encoded_output[:, -1, :])  # predict next rtg given s, a
        next_state_preds = self.predict_state(encoded_output[:, -1, :])  # predict next state given s, a

        return next_state_preds, return_preds


And this is my training loop:
scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.8, patience=10, verbose=True)

total_loss_run1 = []
beta_log_schedule = np.logspace(-2,0,num_epochs+1) # scale reconstruction loss

for epoch in range(200):
    predicted_next_states, predicted_rewards = transition_network.forward(timesteps, states, actions)
    # Compute loss
    state_loss = F.mse_loss(predicted_next_states, next_states.squeeze(1))
    kl = transition_network.kl_divergence()
    elbo = state_loss + beta_log_schedule[epoch]*kl    
    # reward_loss = F.mse_loss(predicted_rewards, rewards) # not used for now
    loss = elbo

    # Backward pass and optimize
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(transition_network.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
    avg_loss = loss/len(timesteps)

    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step(avg_loss)

    total_loss_run1.append(loss.item())

This is how the training is going:
Epoch: 1    state_loss: 11.50704    KL div: 248.96251   Scaled KL div: 2.60577

Epoch: 10   state_loss: 0.30527     KL div: 286.4996    Scaled KL div: 4.52006

Epoch: 20   state_loss: 0.16189     KL div: 58.97964    Scaled KL div: 1.46805

Epoch: 30   state_loss: 0.40363     KL div: 33.23243    Scaled KL div: 1.30503

Epoch: 40   state_loss: 0.21593     KL div: 8.24302     Scaled KL div: 0.5107

Epoch: 50   state_loss: 0.14042     KL div: 2.35475     Scaled KL div: 0.23017

Epoch: 60   state_loss: 0.09953     KL div: 0.7468      Scaled KL div: 0.11517

Epoch: 70   state_loss: 0.18755     KL div: 0.48184     Scaled KL div: 0.11723

Epoch: 80   state_loss: 0.16952     KL div: 0.18028     Scaled KL div: 0.0692

Epoch: 90   state_loss: 0.21111     KL div: 0.36034     Scaled KL div: 0.21822

Epoch: 100  state_loss: 0.12067     KL div: 0.08813     Scaled KL div: 0.08421

The ideal agent should always take a right step (action=1) and transition from 0 to 4 to 8 but these are the state predictions from this trained model (they are terrible and vary a lot):
Current state: 0    Action: 0   next_state mean: 4.24 var: 7.2624
Current state: 0    Action: 1   next_state mean: 4.28 var: 7.52159
Current state: 3    Action: 0   next_state mean: 3.92 var: 6.59359
Current state: 3    Action: 1   next_state mean: 3.84 var: 7.4944
Current state: 4    Action: 0   next_state mean: 4.3 var: 7.49
Current state: 4    Action: 1   next_state mean: 4.14 var: 7.0804

I have tried a lot of different hyperparameter values for learning_rate (best=1e-1), prior (best=1.0), hidden_dims (tried from 2 to 64), num_ecoder_layer (2 & 4) and dropouts. Increasing the dropout to 0.5 does reduce the KL divergence but the next_state predictions are still nonsensical and never the same.
I am wondering if I have implemented this wrong? Or is my approach itself wrong?
Also, would it make more sense to implement the BayesFormer way?
